# could not find react-redux context value ; ensure component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, next.js

I'm working on nextjs project and i'm getting the following error when i try my tests

***could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`***

```
27 | const Home = () => {
  28 |   const classes = useStyles();
> 29 |   const dispatch = useDispatch();
     |                    ^
  30 | 
  31 |   const movies = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.movies.movies);
  32 |   const isMovieSaving = useSelector(
```

I'm getting this error only when using the useDispatch hook.

_app.tsx

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Container className={classes.root}>
          <Header />
          <div className={classes.contentContainer}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </div>
          <Footer links={[Instructions, Design, Swagger, Storybook]} />
        </Container>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

index.tsx

```
const Home = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <MoviesList
        movies={movies}
        getRating={getRating}
        saveMovie={saveMovie}
        formBackgroundColor={formBackgroundColor}
      />
    </div>
  );


export default Home;
```

The error says that i should wrap the component with Provider. But i have already done in _app.tsx. I tried wrapping the Home component with Provider as well, but got the same result. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: _"But i have already done in _app.tsx"_ - What component are you testing? `App` or `Home`? If the latter you'll need to wrap it in the provider in your test too, since the `Provider` from `App` will not be present when testing `Home` in isolation.

Comment: Is there a way to not wrap Provider each time i write tests? Btw wrapping in test with the provider worked.

Comment: No, there isn't another way. The component needs to be wrapped by the provider.

Comment: Hi, would you give feedback about my answer? with best regards

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a `configTest.js` to set up some details with the test.

since your `Home` component is using the redux provider (or any provider), you need to set up a test provider in `configTest.js`. in this example I use the `render` method (from the react testing library) and then create another `customRender` function and export it, you can also set up this method with jest.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';

import ReduxProvider from './providers/redux-provider';
import RouterProvider from './providers/router-provider';

afterAll(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

const AllTheProviders = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <ReduxProvider>
      <RouterProvider>
        {children}
      </RouterProvider>
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
};

const customRender = (ui, options) => render(ui, {wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options});

export * from '@testing-library/react';
export * from '@testing-library/jest-dom';

export {customRender as render};
```

Now in your test file, you need to import `render` and other methods from this file instead of importing them from the testing library or jest library

```
import {render, fireEvent, screen} from 'configTests';
```